# Simulate Oracle SPOOL in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqlplus, spool

HI,

I am converting a shell script to a Java program. The shell scripts runs an sql statement and spool the file to an external text file. I want to simulate this in Java. (The output file must be in the exact same format as it was generated in running the comman in SQL+). Can anyone give me some guidelines such as formatting spacing ... for the file

Thanks

Comment: Surely just writing to standard output and having this redirected to a file would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

First, is this a fixed query, or an arbitrary one? If it's fixed, you'll have an easier time. Arbitrary queries will have to be run via dbms_sql, so you can return column attributes. That's messy.

Second, keep in mind that SQL*Plus formatting is controllable by settings in the client. Things like line length, page size, column widths, headers, etc. are all able to be changed from execution to execution.

That said, assuming it's a fixed query, then I'd:

1. open a cursor for the query
2. If there's data, print the column headers (including the '------' lines)
3. loop through the cursor, printing each value for the record in proper format
4. close the cursor

You should be able to format your output by examining the output from SQL*Plus and copying that.

Comment: Why would you need dbms_sql?!? You can just parse a statement and inspect the MetaData instead!

Comment: Not sure how to do that, actually. Got any links?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, @ammoQ is referring to the `ResultSetMetaData` returned by `ResultSet.getMetaData()`. Once you have that, you wouldn't need to rely on `dbms_sql`, correct?